# linq queries using if

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is it possible to do a query that contains an `if`? What I'd like to do is to select two certain columns based on the value of another column in the same table.

So if the value of `column1` is `0`, I'd like to select `custom1` and `custom2`, if it's `1`, I'd like to select `custom3` and `custom4`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do If statement in Linq Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153486/how-to-do-if-statement-in-linq-query)

Comment: That one looked pretty complicated, but I guess you're right. The answer I was "looking for" was that it's possible to do conditional operators in linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var q = from c from MyTable
        select new
        {
            item1 = (c.column1 == 0) ? custom1 : custom3,
            item2 = (c.column1 == 0) ? custom2 : custom4
        }
```